# htmlで画像の変更が適用されません

Tags: html, css

最初に適用した画像から他の画像に差し替えたのですが、
最初の画像が常に表示されている状態です。
この問題の解決方法が分かる方がいましたら、ご教授お願いします。

対象の画像はCSSにて、下記のように指定しているasc.gifです。

```
background-image: url(asc.gif);
```

またasc.gifは下記画像のように配置されています。

[image: 画像の配置]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSSはリロードしても更新されないことがありますので、
Ctrl+F5でスーパーリロードするか、クエリー文字を追加するなどして対処してください。

http://weboook.blog22.fc2.com/blog-entry-367.html

Answer (score 1):

おそらくブラウザにキャッシュが残っています。
ブラウザのキャッシュをクリアしてみてください。